# Correctly distributing a Java application with database

Tags: mysql, distribution, java

I have this Java application which uses a MySql Database which I want to distribute. My concern is that, to distribute this application I'll need to make the assumption that the target system has both JRE and MySql Server installed.

Is there any way I could bundle my application with the JRE and the MySql server so that if they aren't already present on the system, my app can install them and then run the application?

Comment: You should look at tools like Chef or Puppet. They can ensure that the prerequisites for your application are present (and install it if they are not).

Comment: Which operating system are you talking about here? e.g. Most current GNU/Linux distributions have a package manager. And most of these will have appropriate packages for MySQL and the Java runtime, and a specific way to install them, depending on the distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You CAN bundle a JRE with a Java application, provided that you follow certain conditions.  (If I recall correctly, this is covered by the standard Sun/Oracle license that you agree to when you download the JRE.  I think the phrase is a "binary distribution" or "binary redistribution".)

**UPDATE**

I just checked, and my memory is correct.  See Supplemental License Terms section of ["Oracle Binary Code License Agreement for the Java SE Platform Products and JavaFX"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html).  (Paragraph C is the most directly applicable to your scenario.)  And as I said above, conditions apply.

**END UPDATE**

I don't believe that you are permitted to bundle the free version of MySQL.

---

Personally, I would recommend AGAINST doing this for Java, because:

1. It inflates the size of your distributable.
2. It fills the user's disc with extra copies of the JRE.
3. It presents a problem if it becomes necessary to patch the bundled JRE that the user has (unwittingly) installed.
4. You are making it difficult for the (sophisticated) user to choose which version of Java to use.

Comment: Are you sure about `JRE`?From some experience I have it is not ok.At least after Oracle got into the picture

Comment: I agree though with the 3 notes.I have seen these problems and are true. +1 for mentioning these

Comment: What if i chose to install JRE if no JRE is present already. that couldn't cause extra copy issues right?

Comment: @AnuragRamdasan - how will you determine that no JRE is installed?  Where will you look?  This is NOT a simple problem.

Comment: @AnuragRamdasan:Your deliverable will be over enlarged by arround 80+ MB due to JRE.Also the automatic updates will not work.Additionally if the user downloads JRE at a later time he will have your extra copy.

Comment: @StephenC - i wasn't sure of it, just tried to play around with the idea that came to my mind. so i guess the best way would be to just ask the user to download it for himself right?

Answer (score 6):

No you should not bundle them and deliver them as part of your installation because of licensing.
This applies to both Oracle JRE and MySQL.

**Update after @Stephen C comment.**
It seems that it is possible to redistribute the JRE provided certain circumstances.It is illadviced though for the reasons that are explained in Stephen C answer. I have seen these issues arise in practice.
**End Update**

I am not sure what is the "safest" path (safest related to licensing issues).
Perhaps an installer that downloads them on the spot as part of the required components is ok.Friends here can correct me if I am wrong on this

Comment: Very true, I strongly support this answer, but you can use detection scripts to detect if JRE and MySQL are installed in the system and redirect him to the websites if they are not installed.

Comment: so the best option for me would be to scan the system and on not finding a jre or mysql just prompt the user to download one? no other option?

Comment: @AnuragRamdasan:Yes propmt the user.This is a common "feature" in installations.If your app is not commercial you still should study carefully all licensing details for both MySQL and JRE.Note that licensing fees are high

Comment: Actually, the Oracle Java SE and Java FX licenses **specifically allow** embedding of JRE distributions under some circumstances; see the link in my Answer.