# Executable Java application (JAR) with database packaged inside

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing, deployment

I am developing an application with Swing and MySql. I want to distribute it to the clients, where they could run the application on their end/PC without worrying about installing MySql and other technical stuff. So, I thought of bundling JRE and MySql but then I came across [Correctly distributing a Java application with database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10190202/418556) which says it is not preferable to do so. As it would increase the application size on disk, which obviously is an issue.

So, my questions are

1. How do I achieve the same and what tool and resources should I use.
2. Is SQLite a good option?

**Any help is appreciated.**

Comment: Is the DB 'read only'?  BTW - The best way to deploy a Java desktop application is using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  It includes a special section of the launch file to call an installer that you might use to set up and populate the DB, and a serialization mechanism that will allow the installer to write whatever parameters are needed for the main app. to access the DB.

Comment: *"Correctly distributing a Java application with database which says it is not preferable to do so. As it would increase the application size on disk,"*  (shrugs)  If the app. needs a DB, it needs a DB.  The options are to either rely on the user pre-installing the DB or to install one for the use of the app.  The first is not very reliable, while the 2nd will cost more bytes in download.

Comment: No the DB is read/write and of course will look into Java Web Start.

Comment: Yes, those two options are a heck. That why searching for a soution which would serve the purpose.

Comment: What would be the optimum solution according to you @Andrew Thompson? I would really appreciate your suggestion

Comment: I won't advise on the DB because I don't have experience with them.  As to 'presume present/install a DB' I'd go with 'install a (light) DB'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion SQLite and Apache Derby (http://db.apache.org/derby/) are both good for such a plan. Some years ago i did such stuff with derby and it's still running. At that time i just packaged the folder that contained the jre, the program, libs (jar's) and the data folder of derby.
As i remember: sqlite was very easy to use whereas derby is more overhead to learn.

Comment: Can you please provide the information on how to bundle them? Would very much appreciate that

Comment: It was just a zipped folder as mentioned above. The zip contains the jre, all needed jars, the data folder of derby and a batch file to start the jre. There is no special trick to know about.

Comment: **Thanks a lot** @chris for the awesome idea, you saved me a lot of time. 
Accepted the answer.
And while searching the web about Apache Derby/Java DB came across an awesome [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k6rZHu0_mfw) which explains every corner of it and actually gives a lot of information about why should we use it. Cheers!!!

Comment: Yes, it was. Because for a beginner like me who wants to learn just needs an initiation, that's it. And I was confused with the database storm and all technical stuff in the middle of the development sea. So, it helped a lot. Cheers, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try using HsqlDb visit the link 
[http://hsqldb.org/ ]

Easy to use and you can embed it into your jar.

Comment: You should also mention some components of the link here, as when the link die the users will be unable to access the content. **"As it is now", there is no content in your provided link**