# How to store data locally on a computer?

Tags: database

I want to develop a Java based desktop application, in which I want to use MySQL or any other database for storing data. Then I want to make my application bundle in a one file package for distribution.

Distributed execution file can be installed in any operating system (Mac, Linux, Windows). But the problem is, general people don't want to install MySQL or any other database. So what is the good way to pack everything inside my bundle package so that only one click installation is sufficient to run my application smoothly?

If I don't use SQLite, is there any way to pack other database in my application? Or suggest me a better way for this plan.

Comment: You can always use SQLite.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executable Java application (JAR) with database packaged inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323276/executable-java-application-jar-with-database-packaged-inside)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include SQLite database in executable Jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019974/how-to-include-sqlite-database-in-executable-jar)

Comment: No it's  not. I don't want to use SQLite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any Database, but you have package that DBMS software in your installer. 
You have to create different installers based in the Operating Systems that you want to support.
For every OS based installer you have to write different scripts which you have embed in your installer. Like for Windows you can write Powershell script which will extract the installer and install different softwares required. As for your DBMS you need to provide username and password. So you need to write a script which will ask this input from user (It can be a small window).

Another solution that you may like to look into, you can write a Docker image and can run a docker container.